# Android BroadcastReceiver OnReceieve not hit

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I've a broadcast receiver and it is not getting hot even though the broadcasts re registered in the manifest.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.trial.trialservice"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="BA_1.00.0.0.001"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
    />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material" >
        <service
            android:name="com.trial.trialservice.TrialService"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.encoding.permission.TRIAL_ACCESS" >
        </service>
        <receiver android:name=".TrialHandler" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.trialmanager.TRIAL_STATUS_UPDATED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the handling part of the code:

```
public class TrialHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String TAG = "TrialHandler";
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Inside TrialHandler onReceive, Intent: "+intent);
        mContext = context;
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) ||
                intent.getAction().equals("com.trialmanager.TRIAL_STATUS_UPDATED")){
            // My business logic goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does the first log gets printed? The Inside bla bla?

Comment: "Inside TrialHandler onReceive, Intent:" - This never gets printed. Hence looks like onReceive is not getting called at all.

Comment: Have you tried to put the full `android:name=com.blalba.TrialHandler`? Or remove the "."

Comment: Yes, tried "com.trial.trialservice.TrialHandler" instead of ".TrialHandler". No improvement.

Comment: And without the "."? Just TrialHandler?

Comment: Also in which device are you testing it? And what's the TRIAL_STATUS_UPDATED? it comes from outside the app?

Comment: Could you also add this `android:exported="true" android:enabled="true"` in the receiver?

Comment: Tried without the "." and also added android:exported="true" android:enabled="true". No improvement yet.

Comment: The broadcast comes from another application

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205703/discussion-between-skizo-oziks-and-webgenius).